# How to set placeholder text color on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, colors

I have placeholder text inside an input form field that I **can't** seem to change color to white, it comes out as grey, but only on Firefox. Chrome browser seems to be fine.

When you type into the field the correct color displays, it's just the initial placeholder that is not responsive.

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" placeholder="my placeholder" maxlength="30" name="myplaceholder">
```

css:

```
input#myinput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
}
input#myinput::-moz-placeholder { 
    color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC;  
}
input#myinput:-moz-placeholder { 
    color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
}
input#myinput::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
}   /* IE10+ */

input[type="text"]{
    width:170px; height:16px; padding:12px 5px; border:none; 
    color:#FFF; font:14px/14px 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-align:center; background-color:#CCC;
}
```

[Heres my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/vc8V4/)

Comment: I suspect that's more down to font rendering differences than anything else although other colors do seem a little 'washed out'.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Add `opacity: 1` to the Firefox placeholders.

```css
input#myinput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
}
input#myinput::-moz-placeholder { 
      color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC;  
    opacity: 1;
}
input#myinput:-moz-placeholder { 
      color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
    opacity: 1;
}

input#myinput::-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE10+ */
      color:#FFF; background-color:#CCC; 
}     

input[type="text"]{
    width:170px; height:16px; padding:12px 5px; border:none; color:#848484; font:14px/14px 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; background-color:#CCC;
}
```

```html
<input id="myinput" type="text" placeholder="my placeholder" maxlength="30" name="myplaceholder">
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x4oafn9j/)

Answer (score 6):

```
//PLACEHOLDER EXAMPLE

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #666;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #666;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #666;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #666;
}
```

Comment: This appears to repeat the solution from Fabricio from two year prior.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #fff;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #fff;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #fff;  
}
```

Comment: i have that,  isnt this the same as my css?

Comment: It is right, but also "opacity: 1" has to be added to the two moz-placeholder definitions

Comment: This is exactly what OP already as. It should be deleted.