# Color for styled placeholder text is muted in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, placeholder

I've changed the color of my placeholders with the relevant vendor prefixes and it's displaying properly in other browsers, but for some reason Firefox mutes the colors a bit.

```
::-moz-placeholder, input::-moz-placeholder {color: Black;}
```

I've used both `:-moz-placeholder` and `::-moz-placeholder` prefixes. Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens if you put black:#000; ? Also try put both version as separate, not comma separated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css - placeholder text color on firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621306/css-placeholder-text-color-on-firefox)

Comment: @Medda86 - I tried both of your suggestions prior to posting and they didn't help :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default placeholder style has an opacity different from 1, so that if you change the input color the placeholder automatically ends up with a slightly muted version of that color.

Try setting `opacity: 1` in addition to the color.

Comment: That did it :-D Any idea why I would have to declare the opacity in Firefox?

Comment: Because the default browser stylesheet has `input::-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0.54; }` in it.  You can see the discussion that led to that behavior in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=556145

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this, just try this once,

```
input[type="text"]:hover::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #000000;
}
```

above is for text inputs if you need for all inputs remove `[type='text']`.
Okay

Comment: I actually want the placeholder color to be set to black when the page loads (not on hover)